# Deployment - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, deployment

My ASP.NET MVC 3 app works fine on my local machine (And usually works fine when i deploy it), but on this occasion i get the following error. The server is windows 2008 R2 with IIS7

EDIT: Bothe ILoggingService & IConfigSettings are both bound in Singleton Scope by Ninject (If That Helps)

Anyone get any pointers on what i should look for?

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
DataPortal.Models.Repositories.KpiRepository..ctor(ILoggingService ls, IConfigSettings configSettings) +1295
DynamicInjector3f592a0195c345d8a7d555c4c4085e12(Object[] ) +128
Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve() +279
System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +237
System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +298
System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() +109
System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +487
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable`1 source) +103
Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context) +479
Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve() +279
System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +237
System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +298
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +67

[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'DataPortal.Controllers.KpiController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +247
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +85
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +280
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass6.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2() +66
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb`1.<ProcessInApplicationTrust>b__a() +19
System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Func`1 func) +161
       System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +405
 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +375
```

Comment: Tiny nitpick: 2008 R2 comes with IIS7.5

Answer (score 3):

it was a dependency issue in the end. The project had a dependency on another project that hadn't been deployed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems one of your argument "LoggingService or ConfigSettings" is not configured properly in your web.config. Check your previous working version config file.

Comment: Both the Web.config on my working local copy and the not working test server copy are exactly the same

Comment: Since you are using Dependency injection make sure you have all dependent dlls are copied into the bin directory in the deployed location. Compare the bin directory of your working and non working folder. That may help.

Comment: Thanks i've already done that. Interestingly the deployed location had one more file than my local folder

Comment: shouldn't be a problem what file is that. Try the below two options 1. Rebuild and republish. 2. Try deploying it into a different machine and see. By the way are you using any third party application that installs it dll into gac? Are you referring any such dll through dependency injection? if so make sure you installed those dlls into deployed server GAC

Comment: The file that's different is an Oracle dll that's not used in this part of the application anyway. I'm going to deploy it to another server and see how taht goes.

Comment: Production server exhibiting eactly the same problem

Answer (score 0):

In some cases it can be related to a problem with the database for example :

a select which returns a null value without a correct exception handling would cause the same error. Therefore,one needs to check his sql requests.